# classNotFoundException: jfxtras.scene.control.CalendarTimeTextField

Tags: javafx, java-11, jfxtras

I want to use jfxtras CalendarTimeTextField in my `JavaFX` application.

I added `jfxtras-common-17-r1.jar` and `jfxtras-controls-17-r1.jar` in classPath.
I added the `CalendarTimeTextField` in `SceneBuilder`.

I saved the FXML in SceneBuilder and refresh the project in Eclipse (2023-06).

Eclipse VM arguments:

```
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\openJDK\javafx-sdk-20.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.base,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing --add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap=ALL-UNNAMED
```

After running the application in Eclipse, I get a ClassNotFound Exception

```
ClassNotFoundException: jfxtras.scene.control.CalendarTimeTextField
```

I use openJDK20.0.1, JavaFX20, JavaFX Scene Builder 20.0.0

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks
GGK

[image: Java Build Path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked it by myself.
The jfxetra libraries aren't configured in
`run configurations -> Dependencies` Tab

added there and it runs.